# Prove lineality for a sublinear function

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I want to prove that for a **sublinear** function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the lineality space $\mathrm{lin}f:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d|-f(x)=f(-x)\}$ is the largest subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ on which $f$ is linear. Here we say $f$ is sublinear if $f$ satisfies $$f(\lambda x+\mu y)\leq \lambda f(x)+\mu f(y)\quad\mathrm{for\;all}\;x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d,\quad \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}_+.$$
I already can prove that for $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$. To prove the lineality, now just need to prove $\forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^d$, the equality $$f(x_1)+f(x_2)=f(x_1+x_2)$$is true. The sublineality of $f$ already gives $f(x_1+x_2)\leq f(x_1)+f(x_2)$, however I do not know how to prove the inverse inequality. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1,x_2\in lin f$.

$$f(-x_1-x_2) \le f(-x_1)+f(-x_2) = - f(x_1) - f(x_2) = -(f(x_1)+f(x_2))\le -f(x_1+x_2)$$

where we used sublinearity in the first and fourth and $x_1,x_2\in lin f$ in the second step. Since you already know that $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ we see that actually there holds equality in all steps above, i.e. $f(-x_1-x_2)=f(-x_1)+f(-x_2)$, and ultimatively $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$.